# Generating sets of ids in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table with some data which I create extracts from:

```
id  data1  data2  data3  data4
-----------------------------
1   foo    bar    baz    foo
2   bar    foo    foo    foo
1   foo    doo    goo    omo
```

An id might have more than one record in that table. Before giving people a copy of the data, I want to replace all identifiers with something different but keep the records consistent. For example, all records with id = 1 should still have the same identifier in the new table.

Is there an efficient way of doing this in SQL/MySQL? So far, the only thing I have thought of is creating a separate table of ids and manipulating the original ones somehow.

Edit

The output I would like would be:

```
AAA foo bar baz foo
BSF bar foo foo foo
AAA foo doo goo omo
```

Essentially, I do only need to obfuscate the id part and replace it with another id that is consistent across the output. i.e. the same source id will get the same replacement id in the output

Comment: You want to obscure the id value only - is that right?  Pls provide an example of the output you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a unique* ID by hashing your original values with a salt. Examples of hash functions could be [`MD5()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_md5), [`SHA1()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_sha1) or [`SHA2()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_sha2).

An example query to get the modified table could be:

```
SELECT SHA1(CONCAT('replace_this_here', id) AS id, data1, data2, data3, data4
FROM tablename
```

It'll be very unlikely that someone'll find a way to determine your ids easily, unless they obtain the salt you use (`'replace_this_here'`), so if you use a random string there, you'll be pretty good as far as obscuring the original id goes.

*: Not guaranteed unique, but you're unlikely to get two matching values. If interested in more information, read up on hash collisions.